# What is "fabs" in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, c

Found this bit of code...

```
if(fabs([tempPlacemark getCoordinate].latitude-latitude) < latDelta && fabs([tempPlacemark getCoordinate].longitude-longitude)<longDelta )
...
```

refers to this in Math.h:

```
extern float fabsf(float);
extern double fabs(double);
extern long double fabsl(long double);
```

So what am I looking at?

Comment: Did you look for any documentation?

Comment: That's not Objective-C by the way, that's plain C.

Comment: When the header lacks comments like this (which is common for libc and Unix headers), you can often option-click a function to get more expressive documentation in a popover.

Comment: @darkheartfelt: The main objection here is probably that this would have been trivially answerable in less time via e.g. a [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=math.h+fabs).

Comment: @rdelmar That code most certainly *is* Objective-C. Objective-C is a superset of C, and so it includes C functions like fabs.

Comment: @JimBalter, well, I guess I'm just making a distinction between what is "pure" Objective-C, and what it inherits from C by being a superset. I didn't mean to imply that it's not included in the code you can use in Objective-C.

Comment: For ObjC/Cocoa questions, one of your first ports of call should always be  [a search of Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/). For example: ["fabs"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=fabs) there gives you the relevant man page.

Comment: Hey, future people: It calculates an absolute value. So a positive number stays positive, and a negative number becomes positive. 0 is 0.

Comment: and now this answer is actually the top result by [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=objective+c+fabs) :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`double  fabs( double )` - returns the absolute value of the argument

`NSLog(@"res: %.f", fabs(10)); //result 10`
`NSLog(@"res: %.f", fabs(-10)); //result 10`

[found here.](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/objective-c-math-functions/)